# Search for nodes having a certain attribute with htmlagilitypack

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I have only seen examples on how to search for nodes where attributes have or contain certain values but I cannot find one where you search for nodes where the attribute exists to start with.

How is that done?

Comment: Just loop over it ? foreach(HtmlNode matchedNode in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//*[@attrX])  { }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to just loop over it :

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = htmlWeb.Load("somewebsite.org");    
foreach(HtmlNode matchedNode in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@attrX]") {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Never though about using the asterisk!