# Not able to parse meta tag from html accordingly

Tags: c#, regex

I was parsing meta tag from HTML. Everything working fine but in some case, i am not able to parse meta tag accordingly.

**Here is tag format** :  `<meta property="fb:pages" content="6456456"/>`

**Regex** : `string regexImgSrc = @"<meta property.*?>";`

But sometimes I get meta tag in another format from html like this:

```
<meta data-react-helmet="true" property="article:publisher" content=""/>
```

So Regex is not getting the expected output.
I need only property name and content from meta tags. 
Here is my code

```
      string regexImgSrc = @"<meta property.*?>";      
      MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(htmldata, regexImgSrc, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not recommended to use regex for parsing html.  html is not regular and regex is for regular expressions.

Comment: why you are not using html parsing library (Html Agility Pack). Its just a suggestion

Comment: No, I don't want to use any library or third party tool @Usman

Comment: `<meta property.*?>` is really a bad way of matching a tag name with an attribute name, as attribute order is not fixed. `property` attribute may be at the start, end or at another place. That is why HTML/XML parsing is done with special libraries. With XPath, it is just `//meta[@property]` - easy and readable.

Comment: But everything is working perfectly for "<meta property="fb:pages" content="6456456"/>" these type of tags @jdweng

Comment: I just need a regex to get only property or content from meta tags, Is this possible by using regex? @Wiktor

Comment: @sachin imagine it would be `<meta content="6456456" property="fb:pages" />`

Comment: Yeah, everyone says "but it is working perfectly", until they find themselves in the situation like yours. Or even worse. A regex is only possible with some assumptions. And once an HTML/XML string does not meet these assumptions, your code won't work.

Comment: So what should I do now any good suggestions?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c, then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933368/search-for-nodes-having-a-certain-attribute-with-htmlagilitypack. Your XPath is `"//meta[@property]"`

Comment: Also, here is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755221/getting-an-list-which-contains-specific-text-using-regex/33755654#33755654) that will let you do it with HAP easily, just provide the XPath I shared.

Comment: Just for the record, the [Mastering Regular Expression book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) talks about retrieving data from html pages with regexes. At yahoo. Still, it's generally better to use a parser. Just keep in mind, every problem exists in a context. Some contexts are okay with a regex html parsing, while others aren't.

Comment: `string regexImgSrc = @"<meta(?= )[^>]* property=[^>]*>"`

Answer (score 0):

Parsing html with regex works as long as your htmls are very limited. E.g. you just parse a bunch of them, e.g. as a backoffice process. Even in this case you must be willing to change your regex when needed.

Here is a slightly enhanced regex for you. Please note that it still won't match everything:

```
<meta[^>]*?property=("[^"]*"|'[^']*')[^>/]*\/>
```

Demo [here](https://regexr.com/3gtd9).
Explanation:

- `<meta[^>]` matches the start of the tag
- `[^>]*?` matches stuff that's not a closing tag. The `*?` is a lazy quantifier so the match happens slightly faster
- `property=` matches the property attribute
- `("[^"]*"|'[^']*')` allows the property value to be surrounded either with apostrophe or with quotation mark
- then again `[^>/]*` matches stuff up to the end
- then this is the end of the tag `\/>`

So what's the real solution for parsing html? Well, use a html parser like the [HTML agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain, what's wrong. I.e. Doesn't it work? Didn't I  warn OP about the limitations of this regex? Didn't I suggest a parser-based solution too?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue with (simple) regex, you can use this:

```
<meta (?:.*? )*?property.*?>
```

`(?:[^<>]*? )*?` means:

- `?:` don't create a capture group
- `.*?` any char zero or more times, as few times as possible
- space
- `(...)*?` the whole thing zero or more times

In fact, this regex will match any meta tag, which contains the word "property". For instance `<meta some-attr="some property" />` would also be a match.

**It's a quick and dirty way and I also do not recommend to use regex.**

PS: I noted that you could add a `=` after "property" to improve the regex a bit: `<meta (?:.*? )*?property=.*?>`